# Chrome-OS: How is it possible that 3 directories are mounted on the same partition

Tags: mount, chrome-os

I noticed a weird thing on my Chromebook today. It seems like 3 directories are mounted on the same partition and yet have totally different content. I tried googling the issue, but came up with a loot of people trying to have **the same** content in all directories.

When I run `mount | grep /dev/mmcblk0p1` I get:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /mnt/stateful_partition type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /usr/local type ext4 (rw,nodev,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered)
```

However when I inspect each directory I get this.

For `ls /home`

```
chronos  root  user
```

For `ls /usr/local`

```
chronos  root  user
```

And for `ls /mnt/stateful_partition`

```
crouton  dev_image  encrypted  encrypted.block  encrypted.key  home  lost+found  shutdown_stateful_umount_failure  unencrypted
```

I noticed, that **home** is actually a directly in */mnt/stateful_partition*, but I still don't fully understand it.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment I typed the question I figured it out myself. Maybe someone else is curious too.

The output of `mount` is misleading. The partition is only mounted on `/mnt/stateful_partition` and `/home` and `/usr/local` are not mounted on the same partition, but seem to be `mount --bind` to the directories **dev-image** and **home** in `/mnt/stateful_partition`.

**Follow up:** I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/388) to suggest a modification for this behavior.

**Result:** As I learned from [this conversation](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/388#issuecomment-271832594) the problem was, as so often, between chair and keyboard. `mount` is not the correct command, if one wishes to see the **SOURCE** of a directory. It only shows the partition where the data is stored, without structure information.

The solution is to use `findmnt` instead that prints a a nice tree of directories and their source.